# Apache cassandra encryption(not dse)

Tags: ssl, encryption, cassandra

We want to encrypt cassandra table/column/sstable/commitlog/hints. and store the keystore in vault or kms. all of our cassandra instances or ec2 machines. can you please direct me to the documentation how to achieve encryption

Comment: Why do you think that such option exists in OSS Cassandra?

Comment: if not open OSS provides it any other option of third party just for encryption. don't want to spend too much money for dse just for encryption

Comment: I don’t know any other implementation that provides this other than DSE

Comment: In theory - you can enable the disk encryption where the encryption key is implicitly in KMS. You won't see the encrypted values themselves, as the decryption is transparect for your account.

Comment: thanks @gusto2 thois wahat ypou are referring? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-protect-data-at-rest-with-amazon-ec2-instance-store-encryption/

Comment: @car I was thinking about this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html (simpler, more transparent), but effectively achieving the same

Comment: our instance type is  c3.2xlarge. don't see in the listed of supported type of instances. Compute optimized: C4, C5, C5d

Comment: Hi @Alex Ott for TDE encryption of sstables and commit logs. is there a way i can use  aws kms in kmip configuraton. if so can you share me a doc for implementing it

Comment: I'm not sure about this 100% - if I remember correctly, AWS KMS doesn't support KMIP, but this requires checking.